# Integer division

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

I think I found a mistake in the princeton review "Cracking the GRE" 2014 edition on page 408. The problem is as follows:

If $\frac{13!}{2^x}$ is an integer, which of the following represents all possible values of $x$?

a.) $0\le x\le10$

b.) $0\lt x\lt9$

c.) $0\le x\lt10$

d.) $1\le x\le10$

e.) $1\lt x\lt10$

Now princeton review claims the correct answer is d, but $2^0$ is $1$ in my book and $\frac{13!}{1}$ is indeed an integer, thus I would say answer a is correct. Is this really such a glaring error in the book or am I missing something (obvious)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What range of $x$ is permitted? $-1$ works, too. I would accept zero. Typos happen.

Comment: About -1: It's multiple choice and GRE instructions specifically are "select the best answer" so I guess we can just forget about -1. But should be in there, I agreee. And yes sure typos happen but its funny when they list all the prime factors of 13! (obviously also forgetting about 1 there) and then go on to explain to you that $1\le x$... Just checked their errata and its already listed there so at least they are aware of it by now.

Comment: Would not any negative integer value of x satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @User58220:  Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Not only is $0$ a perfectly valid value of $x$, but nowhere in their question or answers do they indicate that they are considering only *integer* values of $x$. $x=\log_2 13$ works just fine, for instance.